# Raspberry Pi でGPIOの値の取得を割り込みを使って行う方法

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, gpio

#### 追記

私が”Socket”と”割り込み”に関して知識がこんがらがっていて、下記の質問内容がおかしくなっています。割り込みを使ってGPIOの値の取得を行う方法を教えて下さい。

---- 以下元の質問文 ---

Raspberry Piでボタンを繋げて押した時に特定の動作をするように以下の様なコードで行っているのですが、自分から`value`ファイルを読みにいくのではなくSocketを使い、変更があった時にだけ受け取るような書き方のほうが良いとアドバイスされました。

```
class Switch
  def initialize(gpio:)
    @gpio = gpio
  end
  def update_status
    case File.read("/sys/class/gpio/gpio#{@gpio}/value").to_i
      when 0 then
        unpush
      when 1 then
        push
    end
  end
  def unpush
  end
  def push
  end
end
switch = Switch.new(gpio: 24)
loop do
  switch.update_status
  sleep(0.1)
end
```

それでドキュメントの`[Socket][1]`項目を読んでみて`Socket.sockaddr_un`を使うのかというアタリはつけたのですが、具体的な使い方がわかりません…。

今回のような場合はどのように`Socket`が使えるのでしょうか？

Comment: 本家の[回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290893/gpio-monitoring-with-select)が参考になるかもしれません。ハードウェアの構成（アクティブロー？、エッジトリガの設定？）などいろいろと質問に書かれていない要素が絡んでいるので、動かなければ補足をお願いします。

Comment: Socketはネットワークで通信するためのインタフェースですから、GPIOの監視には適していません。「ソケット(Socket)」ではなく「割り込み(インタラプト:Interrupt)を使うというアドバイスを受けたのではありませんか。

Comment: ここらへんの知識が全く無くて割り込みをSocketで扱うのかと思ってたのですが、まったく別の物なんですね。「割り込み」だったと思いますので質問のタイトルを変えておきます。

Comment: gpio は「変化があったとき」に読み取れるように設定できるので `select` で取り扱えるんです。一般ユーザーは「割り込みハンドラ」を記述する必要はありませんし、できません。そもそも `select` はネットワークソケットだけを扱う機能ではないですし。